# df.isin returning false when clearly true

Tags: python, pandas

Every month I receive a dataset with a few thousand entries for some accounts. These entries have values that are reported as cumulative, but I need them as month-to-month changes, so I have a script which has been working for about a year now which reads two sets of cumulative datasets, identifies any entries which have changed, and creates a negative entry to delete the previous one and a positive entry to create the correction.

This month the script is telling me that every single entry has been changed when that's clearly not true. To test this, I took a single line from each dataset (calling the lines 'a' and 'b' respectively) in which I confirmed column by column each value matches. Yet a.isin(b) is returning all False.

The script is below. Note that I have it drop the 'asof' column as these are month-specific and would never match between months.

```
def new_rows(montha,monthb):
    global a_new,b_new,matcha,matchb,inverts
    montha=montha.fillna(0)
    monthb=monthb.fillna(0)
    matcha=montha.drop(columns='asof')
    matchb=monthb.drop(columns='asof')
    a_new=montha.loc[matcha[~matcha.isin(matchb)].dropna(how='all').index,:]
    b_new=monthb.loc[matchb[~matchb.isin(matcha)].dropna(how='all').index,:]
    inverts=['gl','al','apd','property','wc','pl','xs','commission']
    a_new[inverts]=a_new[inverts]*-1
    out=b_new.append(a_new)
    out['asof']=monthb['asof'].unique()[0]
    return out
```

Here's line a and b together for comparison (after the script drops the 'asof' column):
[image]

And yet:
[image]

If you're wondering that perhaps there is something different in the entries like whitespace, etc. I checked this again, but before importing the datasets from excel I literally copy-pasted line a to line b so they're truly the same line.

When I run this for any other pair of months I get the results I would expect. Any idea what might be causing this reliable, one-off problem? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that df.isin() will throw an entire row of False values if the indexes don't match. I couldn't find a way around it, so I changed the code to perform left merges onto each set in order to get lists of unique rows:

```
def new_rows(montha,monthb):
    global a_new,b_new,matcha,matchb,inverts,comb
    montha=montha.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
    monthb=monthb.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
    matcha=montha.drop(columns='asof')
    matchb=monthb.drop(columns='asof')
    comb=matcha.merge(matchb.drop_duplicates(), on=matcha.columns.to_list(),how='left', indicator=True)
    a_new=montha[comb['_merge']=='left_only'].copy()
    comb=matchb.merge(matcha.drop_duplicates(), on=matchb.columns.to_list(),how='left', indicator=True)
    b_new=monthb[comb['_merge']=='left_only'].copy()
    inverts=['gl','al','apd','property','wc','pl','xs','commission']
    a_new[inverts]=a_new[inverts]*-1
    out=b_new.append(a_new)
    out['asof']=monthb['asof'].unique()[0]
    return out
```

Hopefully the next person to have this issue stumbles across this post.